# how to cahnge the opening page when connecting using ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh

I want to change the opening page when I connecting using ssh
this is what I have now :

> Welcome to Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
> Last login: Tue Nov 29 13:43:00 2016 from 10.0.0.123

where do I change it 
someone wrote to change /etc/motd but I don't this file 
so waht do I need to change?

Thanks ,

Comment: Why do you want to change it, and what do you want to change it to ?

Comment: I want to change it to "Welcome to my computer - have a nice day! "

Comment: but it doesn't say how to do it , what do I need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Welcome message you see is called **Message Of The Day** generated by **update-motd** package.

Install the package update-motd by:

> $ sudo apt-get install update-motd

Now go to **/etc/update-motd.d/**. 
 You'll find some scripts like 00-header, 99-footer etc.
Modify these files as per your required message and restart the ssh server by:

> $ sudo service ssh restart

Now try to ssh into you machine.

Comment: Doesn't work                                                                                 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package motd-update

Comment: Look for update-motd

Comment: I have found /etc/update-motd.d/.  and change waht I want , but how do I remove this line - Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Updated my answer. Typo in package name. Thanks@Jean-Marie